# IntelliJ 2019 - Image shows when I "Run Gui" but not when I execute the jar

Tags: java, swing, jlabel, embedded-resource, imageicon

I haven't yet found an answer to this in any other posts.  Most give the same instructions but none have worked.

I am using the Swing Designer in IntelliJ.  My resource file is marked as a Resource file.  When I click the Run Gui button the window that pops up looks fine but when I build the jar and execute it the image icon is missing.

How do I get the image to show up in my running application?

My resource file is at the root and is called "rsc".

My JLabel is built like this:

```
private void createUIComponents() {
        // Add the image
        imageMyLogo = new JLabel(new ImageIcon("rsc/myLogo.png"));
    }
```

Comment: This: "_My resource file is marked as a Resource file._" should have continued "_in my Intellij Project's Module settings_". What you have not addressed is how the context is configured in the Jar. It seems clear the "_Resource Path_" in the running context is not the root of your project. There are several ways to solve this, usually with `ClassLoader` and one of the various resource getters such as `ClassLoader.getResource()`. But, there are other ways too. You might find help by reading [this article.](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/lang/resources.html)

Comment: Application resources will become embedded resources by the time of deployment, so it is wise to start accessing them as if they were, right now.  An [tag:embedded-resource] must be accessed by URL rather than file.  See the [info. page for embedded resource](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/embedded-resource/info) for how to form the URL.